# Advanced Wordpress SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

after 4 hours I am not able to find solution, how to correctly write the SQL query to echo data from two tables.

I have two tables and I need to *"JOIN"* theirs data.

First table is `wp_users` and the second is `wp_usermeta`.

From `wp_users` all I need is `user_email` (So it would be `SELECT user_email FROM wp_users`).

But I need to join the other table called `wp_usermeta` where I need a lot of stuff like `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number`, `schoolid`, `schoolname` etc.

And here is the problem :-)

In `wp_usermeta` I need to read data from two columns - `meta_key` and `meta_value`. Column `meta_key` stores the name of the variable (for example `schoolid` and column `meta_value` stores the value of the `meta_key` (for example `XXXXXXXX`).

I have this code:

```
 <table>
        <tr><th>Email Address</th><th>First Name</th></tr>
    <?php
$teacher_table = "SELECT wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
 FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
 WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname'";


$results_table_main = $wpdb->get_results($teacher_table);

 foreach ($results_table_main as $value){
  echo '<tr><td>'.$value->user_email .'</td>';
 echo '<td>'.$value->meta_value .'</td>';
 } ?>
    </table>
```

This works, but I have no idea how to modify it to get more `meta_keys` with their `meta_values`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In WP, you rarely need to "write SQL queries", unless you work with custom tables, instead use its API...

[`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) will join for you **all** meta data attached to each user and return to you plain user objects, so why not use it instead?

Also, see [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)...